gazebo crash gzclient: "The minimum corner of the box must be less than or equal to maximum corner"' failed
Using ros noetic and gazebo 11.13.0
I'm getting this crash while robot is moving
gzclient: /build/ogre-1.9-kiU5_5/ogre-1.9-1.9.0+dfsg1/OgreMain/include/OgreAxisAlignedBox.h:251: void Ogre::AxisAlignedBox::setExtents(const Ogre::Vector3&, const Ogre::Vector3&): Assertion `(min.x <= max.x && min.y <= max.y && min.z <= max.z) && "The minimum corner of the box must be less than or equal to maximum corner"' failed.
linear acceleration and angular velocity become inf.
Any idea how to fix?
Thanks
